# How to use DecisionTreeRegressor() for Categorical Segmentation?

Tags: python, decision-tree

I have used the python's `DecisionTreeRegressor()` to segment data based on a Predictor that is continuous, and it works well.
In the present project I have been asked to use Categorical data as Predictor.
Predictor - Industry Domain, Response - Revenue.
On using `DecisionTreeRegressor()` it threw error

> "Cannot change string to float : Industry Domain".

Can you suggest if there is any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: You could encode both the predictor and the response into integers. Many ways to do it, take a look e.g. to [this link](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/preprocessing/feature_encoding.ipynb). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of decision tree you need to use DecisionTreeClassifier().  It appears that DecisionTreeRegressor only works with numerical predictor data.  DecisionTreeClassifier() only works with class predictor data.  I really wanted one that does both, but it doesn't appear possible.